# SVG style classes in React component

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm trying to integrate an SVG in a React application but I am not sure how to spec the style classes in order to use with React.

I can get the SVG to render and show. But I don't know how to make the classes inside `<defs><styles>`  accessable to the component.

What's the correct way to specify these classes and access them?

In the example below I would like to be able to add the `active` class to `test-logo-1` part of the SVG.

```
const SvgComponent = () => (
<svg id="test" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 860 860">
<defs>
    <style>
       #test-logo-1.active,
      #test_1 .active
      {
        fill: #e5243b;
      }
     ... and more code
   </style>
</defs>
<g id="test-logo">
   <path id="test-logo-1" d="M488.1,264.9l-27.1,70a97.5,97.5,0,0,0-25.5-4.7V255.1A170.28,170.28,0,0,1,488.1,264.9Z" />
    </g>
... more code
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest solution is to create a separate `test.css` file with what I've got inside the  `style` tag.
Then import this: `import "./test.css"`and then I can access and set the classes for the different parts of the SVG.